# Bash script in Python os.system

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to execute the bash script Do_Regr.sh with the following arguments in a linux server:

```
./Do_Regr.sh -i Testlist_Regression.in -m 135.24.237.167 -g
```

How do I run the above in a Python script using os.system() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("./Do_Regr.sh -i Testlist_Regression.in -m 135.24.237.167 -g",shell=True)
```

This should do it.Make sure your python script is also in the same directory or use `os.chdir` to get there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, and another quick question: if I need to do /bin/bash followed by source of some shell script or .env file, then should I follow the same steps? Its like '/bin/bash' followed by source /sf/tools/firmware/fwenv.sh; source ~/griffin.env which I do and then run the above script